# Three.JS Assign material Color to object

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want add a material/color to a loaded object but i dont know the exact syntax better said what vars and function should i add. If i take this line above then it shows the object but the line with material is ignoring.

```
//object loader
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( '3D4.obj', function ( object ) {
    // what should I add here to assign an obj material color?

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000} ));

    // add object to scene
    scene.add( object );
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event )
{
    var object = event.content;
    object.traverse( function ( child )
    {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
            child.material.color.setRGB (1, 0, 0);
    });
    scene.add( object );
});
loader.load( '3D4.obj' );
```

will give you a red object.

Comment: Hi @gaitat that it is possible to draw a border around the material ?? else we can set the `color.setRGB` to the full material, meaning that now the color is applying on the corner of the material

Comment: If I understand what you want is called `rim lighting` but you need to ask a formal question.

Comment: Hi @gaitat question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131593/three-js-add-border-to-material-by-materiel-name-on-loaded-models